# How can I distinguish two keystrokes which have similar responses from getch()

Tags: c, windows

As I said in title, How can I distinguish two keystrokes which have similar responses from getch(). In this code block, K's and left arrow key's getch() responses are same, so when I type capital k case 75 works. How can I fix it? Also I got this problem with some other words.

```
     while(1){
            ch1=getch();
        switch( ch2 = getch())
       {
if(ch1 != 0xE0)
{
             default:
            for(i=' ';i<'}';i++)
            {
                if(i == ch2)
                {
                /*SOME STUFF*/
                printf("%c" , iter->x);
                }
 break;
            }


            else
            {
                case 72: printf("UP WAS PRESSED\n");
            break;
           /*Some other stuff*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keys that do not represent printable characters (like the left-arrow key) don't *have* ASCII codes.

Comment: But when I type capital K, it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't tag your question with both C++ and C: they're different languages, and the solution to a problem for one language is not going to look the same in another language.

Comment: "how can I distinguish two variables which have same ASCII codes" --> " how can I distinguish two keystrokes which have similar responses from `getch()`"

Comment: `getch` is a windows function. Keys that are cursor controls or Fn keys return *two* successive codes. The first is either `0` or `224`. But you must define `int ch2` since that is the return value from `getch()`. You have not shown your variable types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a special character such as left-arrow is pressed, `getch` will first return either the value 0 or 0xE0, then it will return a key code (which is not the same as an ASCII code).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx):

> The `_getch` and `_getwch` functions read a single character from the
>   console without echoing the character. None of these functions can be
>   used to read CTRL+C. When reading a function key or an arrow key, each
>   function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and
>   the second call returns the actual key code.

So you need to check for a 0 or 0xE0 which tells you the next character is a key code, not an ASCII code.

The list of key codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT:

Your `if(ch1 != 0xE0)` is outside of any `case`, so it gets skipped over.  Also, you're always calling `getch` twice when you enter the loop.  So if you didn't get a key code, you end up reading 2 regular characters and most likely skip one of them.

Start you loop with a single `getch`.  Then check for 0 or 0xE0, and if found **then** call `getch` again.

```
while (1) {
    int ch = getch();
    int keycode = 0;

    if (ch == 0 || ch == 0xe0) {
        keycode = 1;
        ch = getch();
    }
    switch (ch) {
    ...
```

Comment: Via Windows, can the keyboard generate a single ^@  - the null character aka ASCII NUL (or maybe a single 0xE0)?  If so, how to distinguish that a another character is due or not?

Comment: The value 0 isn't listed in the set of key codes, and key code 0xE0 is marked as "reserved".  I don't see any mention of null, so it doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: I see the link to Virtual-Key Codes, but having trouble finding the list of the of set of key codes for `a`, `^`, `ctrl z`, etc..  Suggestions?  (found a [Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx) one)

Comment: @chux From what I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx), there are hardware specific scan codes which are translated into virtual key codes.  Not sure how to go about reading the scan codes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dbush, I already tried it but I didn't mention in question, my fault. Still not working. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: Perhaps a link for the set of key codes that has code 0xE0 marked as "reserved" as comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026812/how-can-i-distinguish-two-keystrokes-which-have-similar-responses-from-getch/41026893?noredirect=1#comment69261537_41026893)?

Comment: I write if-else in case's, I mean case 75: if(keycode== blabla, then it worked. Thank you a lot dbush.