# Taking as input only numbers and letters with getch() in c

Tags: c

what I'm trying to accomplish is a simultaneous research by using the fuction getch. I know that this fuction returns a integer value, which represents the ASCII code of a key. Is there any wroten fuction that allows the user to write only certain characters, such as: letters, numbers, and apostrophe.

Comment: You can't oblige the user to write or not to write something. You can accept what you want from whatever was written.

Comment: are you talking about `getch` from `conio.h`?  I don't think that is standard c. If you are talking about something else, I apologize

Comment: Yes, I'm using it from conio.h

Comment: @NiVeR I know that... the point is I have to check every single ASCII code and check if it is different beetween the ones that I allow to the user. It will take really long, I dont wanna be lazy, what I'm asking is if there is already something like this.

Comment: The language has functions like `isalpha` and `isdigit` which are defined in `ctype.h`

Comment: It's good to be lazy and let the computer do the work for you, or use what others have written.

Comment: For ASCII text, you could use a 128/256 byte lookup table for ultimate flexibility.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the replay, by using isalnum and some execptions such as: '\'' , 'è', 'ù' 'à' 'ì' 'ò', I'm almost there, unfortunate F8, F9,F10,F11 and the arrows return as output 1 true and 1 false, if users fail to press one of them it will still be compromised.

Comment: @GeneNight Yes, the arrow keys and function keys are a little harder. They generate a sequence of characters. [Here's a question that may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026812).

Comment: Well, only by printing the output as an integer I managed to do it, I will add my code down below, thank you guys the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
int temp = 0;
while((c= getch()) !='\r')
{
    if ((temp == -32) || (temp == 0))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        if(isalnum((char)c) == 0)
        {
            if((c == '\'') || (c == -118) || (c == -115) || (c == -107) || (c == -123) || (c == -105))
            {
                printf("true: %c\n",c);
            }
            else
                printf("false: %d\n",c);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("true: %c\n",c);
        }
    }
    temp = c;
}
```

For anyone else who's trying to accomplish the same result, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any *write function* that allows the user to write only certain characters, such as: letters, numbers, and apostrophe. (?)

Code can instead selectivity write

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int c; // use type `int` here to distinguish all (256) characters from EOF
while((c = getch()) != '\r' && c != '\n'  && c != EOF) {
  if (isalnum(c) || '\'') {
    putchar(c);
  }
}
```